# Is possible to insert HTML.Actionlink inside LI?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, html-lists, actionlink

I'm trying to insert a `@HTML.ActionLink` element inside a li element using the following code:

```
    var ul = document.getElementById('container');  
    var enlace = '@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Elements", new { id = "5" }, null)';

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My title'));
    li.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    li.appendChild(document.createElement(enlace));
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    ul.appendChild(li);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You're the one who tried it, you tell us. What exactly is the problem with that code?

Comment: You can nest an anchor element inside of a list element, yes.  Whether or not your code successfully does that, we can't know unless you tell us.

Comment: I tried this code but it's not working. The line surrounded by //// does not take effect on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an entire HTML element to `document.createElement()`, which expects only a tag name.  Essentially, you're doing this:

```
document.createElement('<a href="someLink">some text</a>')
```

whereas the function works like this:

```
document.createElement('a');
```

You can probably fix this by separating the creation of the element from the setting of the element's HTML to your custom server-generated HTML.  Replacing just the code surrounded by the comments, it might look like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
var enlaceElement = document.createElement('a');
enlaceElement.innerHTML = enlace;
li.appendChild(enlaceElement);
///////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I have a full demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j99ergpo/).